# Why MLE for uniform distribution doesn't have usual properties?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am now struggling with a problem

> distribution of $x$ is $f(x) = 1/\theta $, $0 \leq x \leq \theta$. We have a random sample from this distribution. Calculate MLE for $\theta$ and explain why some properties of MLE doesn't hold here.

I have shown $\max _{1 \leq i \leq n} X_{i}$ is the MLE of the uniform distribution, but I don't know why some properties of MLE doesn't hold here. I think it has something to do with the regular assumptions on the distribution. Could someone help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The support of the distribution depends on the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: Imagine the real value of $\theta$ is $2$ but all observed values lie in $(0,1)$. Would you say that the MLE is a good estimate of the real value of $\theta$, then?

Comment: This distribution is 'non-regular' in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Regularity_conditions.